# Get last part of an URL as GET parameter

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've got URLs like this:

```
http://example.com/foo/bar/de/
http://example.com/foo/bar/en/
```

Which rewrite rules do i have to use to load the URL before the last "folder" (`http://example.com/foo/bar/`) and get this "folder" as GET parameter (e.g. `lang=de`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^language/(.*)$ index.php?l=$1
```

Now i can open URLs like http://example.com/foo/bar/language/de/ but the browser loads http://example.com/foo/bar/index.php?l=de

Comment: I am testing but my index.php not catch the param ... (any idea why?)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this;

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/foo/bar/$ index.php?lang=$1
```

Comment: Thanks, i've tried it, but i get an 404 error, cause the /en, /de, /.. directory at the end doesn't really exists