# OpenLiteSpeed: Get last part of an URL as GET parameter with rewrite rules

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, rules, litespeed

I want to get the last part of a non-existing URL and then pass it as a GET parameter. Example: http://example.com/store/20 should load  http://example.com/store?id=20

I used the following answer from this:
[Get last part of an URL as GET parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17594309/get-last-part-of-an-url-as-get-parameter)

but it seems like it doesn't really work with OpenLiteSpeed, as I get **404
Not Found**.

I also appended forward slash at the beginning of the rule pattern cf. https://openlitespeed.org/mediawiki/index.php/Help:Rewrite_Rule_Differences, with no difference however.

That is, when I use

```
RewriteRule ^/language/(.*)$ index.php?l=$1
```

under virtual host > rewrite, I receive 404 when accessing  http://example.com/foo/bar/language/de/ where the browser is supposed to load http://example.com/foo/bar/index.php?l=de. I have turned on rewrite and follow symbolic link  , so this is really giving me a headache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^language/(.*)$ index.php?l=$1 [QSA]
```

from

```
https://example.com/language/en
```

to

```
https://example.com/index.php?l=de
```

Try this approach.

Best regards,

Comment: it's weird , I can't type with more explanation , it always warns me some of my content is not formatted as code ...  by the way , remember to restart OLS after you change and save it.

Comment: it worked, i did however had to add a slash before language